# Bounding the edges belonging to no perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

We are told to let $G = (X \cup Y, E)$ be a bipartite graph with $|X|=|Y|=n$, and to suppose that $G$ has a perfect matching. I am trying to find a way to prove that $G$ has at most $n \choose 2$ edges belonging to no perfect matching, and to construct examples that show that this bound is the best possible for every $n$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Expanding $n \choose 2$ to $(n^2 - n)/2$, I am trying to find a way to use the fact that the maximum number of edges one can include in a perfect matching is $n/2$ if we start with $n$ vertices. However, we are starting with $2n$ vertices, so this is just n. Subtracting this from $2n^2$, the number of possible edges, gets me close but isn't the right answer, so I'm still confused. I wouldn't be asking for help if I found it easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the vertices with $X=\{x_i\mid i=1,\dots,n\}$ and $Y=\{y_i\mid i=1,\dots,n\}$ such that $M=\{\{x_i,y_i\}\mid i=1,\dots,n\}$ is a perfect matching. Assume, towards contradiction, that we have more than $\binom{n}{2}$ edges which is not in any perfect matching. Partition $E(G)\setminus M$ to $E_{i,j}=\{\{x_i,y_j\},\{x_j,y_i\}\}\cap E(G)$ for $i<j$ and $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ (Some part may be empty though). By our assumption (and pigeonhole principle), there is some pair $i<j$, $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, such that $E_{i,j}$ has two edges which are not in any perfect matching. This is a contradiction, since $(M\setminus \{\{x_i,y_i\},\{x_j,y_j\}\})\cup E_{i,j}$ is a perfect matching.

For tight example, let $X=\{x_i\mid i=1,\dots,n\}$, $Y=\{y_i\mid i=1,\dots,n\}$, $M=\{\{x_i,y_i\}\mid i=1,\dots,n\}$, $R=\{\{x_i,y_j\}\mid i<j,i,j=1,\dots,n\}$ and $G=(X\cup Y,M\cup R)$. Obviously, $M$ is a perfect matching for $G$. Claim that $M$ is the only one perfect matching. If it does not hold, then there exists some perfect matching which does not contain $e_i=\{x_i,y_i\}$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, But this is not possible, since $|\Gamma_{G-e_i}(\{x_1,\dots,x_i\})|=i-1<|\{x_1,\dots,x_i\}|$.

Comment: The example looks good, but I do not understand the first part. Why must  both $\{x_i,y_j\}$ and $\{x_j,y_i\}$ in an $E_{i,j}$ actually be edges of $E(G)$?

Comment: There is exactly $\binom{n}{2}$ such pairs of "$i,j$", so by pigeonhole principle, at least one $E_{i,j}$ has two edges involved, that is that whole $E_{i,j}$.

Comment: @Casteels Thanks for reminding the partition, just edited!

Comment: Ok I get your point now. I think partitioning may not be the best word to use here since some of those sets may be empty or have just one edge, but that's just nitpicking semantics. Nice answer.

Comment: You are welcome, I am also nitpicking, but this time rush.