# Finding maximum number of edges belonging to no perfect matching in a complete bipartite graph with partite set cardinality $|X|=|Y|$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

Here's my problem:
Let G be a subgraph of $K_{20,20}$. If G has a perfect matching, prove that G has at most 190 edges that belong to no perfect matching.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218258/bounding-the-edges-belonging-to-no-perfect-matching) for a more generalized version of this question, i.e. there're at most $n \choose2$ such edges in any $K_{n,n}$. However, I don't understand that answer's partition or how assuming there are >$n \choose2$ such edges provides a contradiction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the vertices of $G$ be $\{u_k:k=1,\ldots,20\}$ and $\{v_k:k=1,\ldots,20\}$, numbered so that $\{u_kv_k:k=1,\ldots,20\}$ is a perfect matching. Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the set of pairs of distinct integers from the set $[20]=\{1,\ldots,20\}$; note that $|\mathscr{P}|=\binom{20}2=190$.

For each $\{k,\ell\}\in\mathscr{P}$ let

$$E(\{k,\ell\})=\{u_kv_\ell,u_\ell v_k\}\cap E(G)\;.$$

In other words, for each pair of distinct indices $k$ and $\ell$ we look at the potential edges $u_ku_\ell$ and $u_\ell v_k$ that ‘cross’ the matching $\{u_kv_k,u_\ell v_\ell\}$ of the vertices $u_k$ and $u_\ell$ with the vertices $v_k$ and $v_\ell$ and keep any that are in $G$. If neither is in $G$, $E(\{k,\ell\})=\varnothing$; if $u_kv_\ell$ is an edge of $G$ but $u_\ell v_k$ is not, then $E(\{k,\ell\})=\{u_kv_\ell\}$; and so on.

- Verify that if $\{k,\ell\}$ and $\{r,s\}$ are distinct members of $\mathscr{P}$, then $E(\{k,\ell\})\cap E(\{r,s\})=\varnothing$.

Now suppose that $G$ has more than $\binom{20}2=190$ edges that are not in any perfect matching of $G$; I’ll call these edges *bad*. Each edge $u_kv_k$ with $k\in[20]$ belongs to the perfect matching with which we started, so each of these bad edges is of the form $u_kv_\ell$ for some $k,\ell\in[20]$ with $k\ne\ell$ and therefore belongs to the set $E(\{k,\ell\})$. There are $190$ such sets and more than $190$ of bad edges, so the pigeonhole principle ensures that some $E(\{k,\ell\})$ contains more than one bad edge. $E(\{k,\ell\})$ contains at most the edges $u_kv_\ell$ and $u_\ell v_k$, so if $E(\{k,\ell\})$ contains at least two bad edges, it must be that $E(\{k,\ell\})$ contains both $u_kv_\ell$ and $u_\ell v_k$, and that both of these edges are bad.

But now consider the set of edges

$$M=\big\{u_rv_r:r\in[20]\setminus\{k,\ell\}\big\}\cup\{u_kv_\ell,u_\ell v_k\}\;.$$

This is obtained from the original perfect matching by replacing $u_kv_k$ and $u_\ell v_\ell$ with $u_kv_\ell$ and $u_\ell v_k$, keeping all of the other $u_rv_r$ edges. $M$ is clearly a perfect matching of $G$, and it includes both of the supposedly bad edges $u_kv_\ell$ and $u_\ell v_k$; this is clearly a contradiction.

The contradiction arose because the pigeonhole principle gave us an $E(\{k,\ell\})$ containing two bad edges, and we were able to apply the pigeonhole principle because we assumed that there were more than $190$ bad edges. The contradiction therefore shows that there cannot be more than $190$ bad edges.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks!

Comment: @298365: You’re welcome! Glad it helped.